# How to change emoji status in Telegram by Telethon?

Tags: telegram, telethon

In the new Telegram update, it is possible for premium users to install emoji status. Is it possible to implement this through Telethon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible once v1.26 is released (which isn't at the time of writing) once [this PR is merged](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/pull/3933). If you install the development version with these changes, or your Telethon version is v1.26 or higher, you can use [`telethon.tl.functions.account.UpdateEmojiStatusRequest`](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/1350fa64f3d78ac639cc5e940ea2cda799648855/Telegram/Resources/tl/api.tl#L1557) to change your status. It will require a [`telethon.tl.types.EmojiStatus`](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/1350fa64f3d78ac639cc5e940ea2cda799648855/Telegram/Resources/tl/api.tl#L1416) instance, which itself requires the `document_id` of the emoji you want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it'd be  actually like that:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.account.UpdateEmojiStatusRequest(
        emoji_status=types.EmojiStatus(
            document_id=-12398745604826
        )
    ))
    print(result)
```

because UpdateEmojiStatusRequest expects a `types.EmojiStatus`, not s string - according to https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/2a6e2fa353d5c4b7ab6a05eef5ce8952c78c2a73/Telegram/Resources/tl/api.tl#L1557